# Linux Mint XFCE, command to launch menu

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, xfce, command, xfce4-terminal

What is the command that launches the whisker menu in the Linux Mint xfce edition. For another distribution that used xfce it was `xfce4-popup-whisker menu` but that doesn't seem to work. I would like to assign the super key to launch the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`.

However the command is only available from a certain version of the whisker menu. Most probably that other distribution had a newer version of it.

Check your currently installed version in the application manager. The newest is 1.1.1, which contains the popup command.

Follow the instructions here to get the newest version:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=141150

Answer (score 0):

- Open Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts, click "Add"
- In the "command" field, enter `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`
- In the next dialog window, press Super_L (The left "Windows" key)

Comment: Note that if you set just the Windows (Super) button for that command you will not be able to use Super in other commands. More kere: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-switch-windows-with-super-tab/2406 and namely my reply there (https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-switch-windows-with-super-tab/2406/13?u=cipricus). I would recommend Super-Space and/or Ctrl-Space, Alt-Space.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, xfce uses the common method of invoking the command using the name of the associated binary. On my system there are a bunch of them including xfce4-popup-whiskermenu in usr/bin/  You can find it on your system by poking around or using

```
locate xfce4-popup-whiskermenu
```

on a command line.

They all seem have man pages so, for example, you can find out about the usage of the xfce4-popup-whiskermenu with the command

man xfce4-popup-whiskermenu

You are not limited to binding only xfce commands to keystrokes, and can start any program using the same command you would use in a terminal.